# Why do I get an error trying to return an HttpResponse from a Django View function?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, python-3.x

I am trying to call a Django View function from a JavaScript code through Ajax. The View function returns an *HttpResponse* which I am trying to print out on the console.

But on the console is displays **'undefined'** and I get an error on the python terminal saying : **'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'**

**View function** is this:

```
@csrf_exempt
def result(request):
     if(request == 'POST'):
             # datafromclient = request.form['mydata'] 
             # finalRes = runAreaReview(datafromclient)
             test = 'testing'
             return HttpResponse(test)
```

**Html code** is this:

```
<div align="center" class="input-line">
     <form class="input-form" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type = "text" id = "ans" class = "form-control" name = "address" placeholder="Type postcode..."><br><br>
        <button id = "homeBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Find info</button><br><br>
     </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript code** is this:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
var plcholder = document.getElementById('ans').placeholder;
var btnres = document.getElementById('ans').value;
if(btnres == '' || btnres == plcholder)
    console.log('you failed');
else
    console.log(btnres);
    var result = callpy(btnres);
    console.log(result);
});

function callpy(input){
var pyres = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:'/result',
    data: { mydata: input }
});
return pyres.responseText;
```

**The error** I am getting is this:

```
self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

*Note: I researched about this issue and previous versions of Django had a bug in it which caused this error but I have a version which is up to date and I still get this error.*

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your view function. And no, returning a response is literally the main thing that Django does: no versions have accidentally returned None instead.

Comment: What's the context of the error?

Comment: @DanielRoseman : About the indentation, I was copy pasting it from my code, something got messed up but the indentation on my code is correct.
And I still think that an earlier version of Django threw this same error which was fixed in its later version. But, it doesn't matter here.

Do you have any idea why I get this error here?

Comment: The errors must be  from `pyres.responseText`, because I don't see any other split happening. Can you print `console.log(pyres)` and see if the response has `responseText` ?

Comment: The indentation is still not correct. What is inside that if block?

Comment: @rrmerugu I tried printing pyres on the consol and it gives me this :

 8000/static/js/mainHome.js:42 Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
Navigated to http://127.0.0.1:8000/
jquery.min.js:6 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/result 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @DanielRoseman : Changed the indentation now. I am just trying to return a string and print it on the console to test if it's working but it doesn't seem like its working and I cannot figure out the reason.

Comment: its returning 500, so there must be some issue with the view ! I just realised that there is still more indentation error in the python view code, but i couldn't edit it .  Could u fix the indentation in the `if` statement and try again.

Comment: @rrmerugu : It still gives me the same error.

Comment: uff. i missed it. it should be  `if request.method == 'POST'`

Comment: @rrmerugu : I changed my view function which just returns a string. 
def result(request)
     return HttpResponse('testing')

But now, it does not give me a 500 error but instead prints 'undefined' on the console

Comment: just to confirm is  `console.log(pyres)` undefined ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140108/discussion-between-r-p-t-and-rrmerugu).

Answer (score 0):

The code fails with 200 because you are using `if(request.method == 'POST'):` instead of `if(request.method == 'POST'):` which is spoiling the output. And use this javascript, it should work

```
@csrf_exempt
def result(request):
     if(request.method == 'POST'):
         # datafromclient = request.form['mydata'] 
         # finalRes = runAreaReview(datafromclient)
         test = 'testing'
         return HttpResponse(test)


function callpy(input){
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:'/result',
        data: { mydata: input },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function() {
           // error handling here 
        },
  });
}
```